# How can I solve this 'Undefined reference' problem?

Tags: openssl, homebrew, ruffle

While trying to install ruffle through Homebrew, I get across the error of: undefined reference to `SSL_get0_group_name'.

Here is the output of the process:

```
brew install --HEAD ruffle-rs/ruffle/ruffle
==> Fetching ruffle-rs/ruffle/ruffle
==> Cloning https://github.com/ruffle-rs/ruffle.git
Updating /home/benjamen/.cache/Homebrew/ruffle--git
==> Checking out branch master
Already on 'master'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
HEAD is now at 6e1e26e0e chore: Update translations from Crowdin
==> Installing ruffle from ruffle-rs/ruffle
==> cargo build --package=ruffle_desktop
Last 15 lines from /home/benjamen/.cache/Homebrew/Logs/ruffle/01.cargo:
   Compiling dirs v5.0.1
   Compiling os_info v3.7.0
   Compiling sys-locale v0.3.1
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: LC_ALL="C" PATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/rust/1.75.0/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-
  = note: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/binutils/bin/ld: /tmp/ruffle-20240109-31311-r1xadv/target/debug/deps/libcurl_sys-7febe95ed6fa6e9f.rlib(openssl.o): in function `ossl_connect_step2':
          /home/benjamen/.cache/Homebrew/cargo_cache/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/curl-sys-0.4.70+curl-8.5.0/curl/lib/vtls/openssl.c:3994:(.text.ossl_connect_step2+0x638): undefined reference to `SSL_get0_group_name'
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
          
  = note: some `extern` functions couldn't be found; some native libraries may need to be installed or have their path specified
  = note: use the `-l` flag to specify native libraries to link
  = note: use the `cargo:rustc-link-lib` directive to specify the native libraries to link with Cargo (see https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#cargorustc-link-libkindname)

error: could not compile `ruffle_desktop` (bin "ruffle_desktop") due to previous error

If reporting this issue please do so at (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/homebrew-core):
  https://github.com/ruffle-rs/homebrew-ruffle/issues

ruffle's formula was built from an unstable upstream --HEAD.
This build failure is expected behaviour.
Do not create issues about this on Homebrew's GitHub repositories.
Any opened issues will be immediately closed without response.
Do not ask for help from Homebrew or its maintainers on social media.
You may ask for help in Homebrew's discussions but are unlikely to receive a response.
Try to figure out the problem yourself and submit a fix as a pull request.
We will review it but may or may not accept it.
```

I tried linking the `openssl` library through the `makefile` in that location:
`/home/benjamen/.cache/Homebrew/cargo_cache/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/curl-sys-0.4.70+curl-8.5.0/curl/lib`

But I had no success there. I have installed openssl through Homebrew as well.
What am I missing here?

I thought I'd get the ruffle install through Homebrew, but it didn't let me.